# Deriving "Chernoff" bound from exponential Markov inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, distribution-tails

Let $X_1, \dotsc, X_t \overset{d}{=} X$, i.i.d., with $E[X]=\lambda<1$ and define $I:=\lambda - 1 - \log \lambda$.

We want to show that $P[X_1 + \dotsb + X_t \geq t ] \leq e^{-I t}$ using the Chernoff bound (exponential Markov inequality)

To do this, we rewrite for some $s>0$

$$P[X_1 + \dotsb + X_t \geq t] = P[e^{s (X_1 + \dotsb + X_t)} \geq e^{st}]\leq \frac{E[e^{s (X_1 + \dotsb + X_t)}]}{e^{st}}= \frac{(E[e^{sX}])^t}{e^{st}}$$
$$=\exp(t (log(E[e^{sX}])-s))$$

but I have no idea how one gets the $I$ out of it, so in particular which $s$ to choose. Do you have some hints for me?

Comment: Can't show *that*. Set $X=\lambda>1$ to see it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me a hint which assumptions we would need to show it? Because we have used this (it was mentioned that it follows easily by the above calculation). In our case we have $0<\lambda < 1$, is this already enough to prove it?

Comment: The general approach is to choose $s$ that minimizes the bound, but since you only need $\log E(e^{sX})-s\le -I(\lambda)$ you could probably do with less.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already thought about that one  (because this is how we proved another chernoff bound in another exercise), but I couldn't think of how one would show this in general, if one only knows that $E[X]=\lambda$, but nothing else about the distribution. Do we need more information about the distribution or is there an easier way to see it?

Comment: You can first try to show it for $X$ concentrated on two points only.